# How can I split a String using Splitter.MapSplitter from Guava until a specific key?

Tags: java, guava

I have a String like `"key1:value1|prop:id|key3:value3|id:ABC.CDE|key4:value4"`, how can I split using [Splitter.MapSplitter from Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.MapSplitter.html) until id key?

- `Splitter.MapSplitter.on('|').withKeyValuePairs(':").split()` returns an unmodifiable Map, so I need to walk through Map until id key and put entries into a new Map in this case. It does not looks an effective solution.
- `String.substring(0, String.indexOf('|', String.indexOf("id")))` is not an option because "id" String can be substring of any value before id key.
- Or I can use two splitter, entrySplitter to split string into entries and keyValueSplitter to split entries into key-value pairs and then put them into a map while specific key hasn't been reached.

What is the best solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "until id key"? Do you mean you want to retain all key-value pairs before "id" and discard the rest?

Comment: Yes. I want to get the following mapping from String above the most effective way: key1 to value1 and prop to id and key3 to value3 and id to ABC.CDE

Answer (score 0):

Other than copying the output of MapSplitter to another Map and manipulate that (assuming the keys order is preserved), I see no other solution than partially parsing yourself.

Your remark about "id" possibly appearing elsewhere is correct, so you need to search something more specific, like `|id:...|` or `id:...|` if `id` is the first key.

```
private static final Pattern ID_REGEX = Pattern.compile("(^|\\|)id:.+?\\|");
...
Matcher matcher = ID_REGEX.matcher(line);
if (matcher.find()) {
    lineForMapSplitter = line.substring(0, matcher.end()-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use `Splitter.MapSplitter` directly, but rather `Splitter#withKeyValueSeparator` (here: `Splitter.on('|').withKeyValueSeparator(':')`. Secondly, in your case the most efficient way would be manually split pairs and then split pairs if your predicate (about key == id) is not met, and not create map until the very end.

TIMTOWDI, but I'm using [jOOL](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL), which has useful methods for your use case. `Seq.seq(Iterable)` is a simple helper for creating stream and, what's more important, [`Seq#limitUntilClosed(Predicate)`](https://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/0.9.12/org/jooq/lambda/Seq.html#limitUntilClosed-java.util.function.Predicate-) will pick up all values until it finds `id` key:

```
private static final Splitter PAIRS_SPLITTER = Splitter.on('|');
private static final Splitter KEY_VALUE_SPLITTER = Splitter.on(':');
private static final String INVALID_ENTRY_MESSAGE = "Chunk [%s] is not a valid entry";

private Map<String, String> homebrewMapSplitter(final String string)
{
    return Seq.seq(PAIRS_SPLITTER.split(string))
            .map(this::createEntry)
            .limitUntilClosed(e -> e.getKey().equals("id"))
            .collect(ImmutableMap.toImmutableMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Map.Entry::getValue)
            );
}

// ~copied from MapSplitter#split(CharSequence)
private Map.Entry<String, String> createEntry(final String entry)
{
    Iterator<String> entryFields = KEY_VALUE_SPLITTER.split(entry).iterator();
    checkArgument(entryFields.hasNext(), INVALID_ENTRY_MESSAGE, entry);
    String key = entryFields.next();

    checkArgument(entryFields.hasNext(), INVALID_ENTRY_MESSAGE, entry);
    String value = entryFields.next();

    checkArgument(!entryFields.hasNext(), INVALID_ENTRY_MESSAGE, entry);

    return Maps.immutableEntry(key, value);
}
```